# Can kubernetes `--force` delete of pods be disabled by administrators?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, sysadmin

Using `kubectl delete pods PODNAME --force` removes the pod from the Kubernetes API without checking the underlying pod deleted successfully.

In most cases this means resources are locked indefinitely, and since there's no list of them anymore it's hard to track them down and correct the issue. The preferred solution is for the end user to contact the kubernetes admins and notify them of the stuck Terminating pod so the admins can go and fix the underlying issue.

Most users adhere to this convention, but there's always the new guy who doesn't know yet and force deletes, which causes trouble.

Is there a way for the kubernetes admins to fully disable force deletes for users?